# Using template class with the incomplete type void

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class :

```
template <typename T>
class myClass
{
public:
    // Many methods...
protected:
private:
    T attribute
    // Other attributes.
};
```

Instantiating an object of type `myClass<void>` does not work, because of `void attribute`.
Can you give me some hints to be able to use objects of type `myClass<void>` without specializing the whole class. Since it has many member functions that rely on the type T, specializing it will lead to code duplication.

Comment: What do you want your `attribute` type to be?

Comment: I don't really understand what the point of this is. Based on what you showed, the only use of the template type is the one causing the problem.

Comment: I want to be able to instantiate an object of type `myClass<void>`, but in this case, `attribute` would be of type `void` which is not possible.

Comment: So, what do you want to happen if somebody tries to declare `myClass<void>`? How it should work? What should happen to `attribute`?

Comment: Well, `attribute` won't be used at all when using an object of type `myClass<void>`.

Answer (score 4):

Create a templated base class containing attribute, specialize it for `void` and inherit from it:

```
namespace detail //Warn end user that he should not use stuff from here
{
    template <typename T>
    struct myClass_base
    {
        T attribute;
    };

    template <>
    struct myClass_base<void>
    {}; //No attribute at all
}

template <typename T>
class myClass: private detail::myClass_base<T>
{
    //rest of definition
};
```

This would make `myClass` lack `attribute` field when instantiating it with type `void`

Answer (score 2):

You can defer the whole problem by using a custom type and specializing that:

```
template<typename T>
struct my_type_t
{
    using type = T;
};

template<>
struct my_type_t<void>
{};

template<typename T>
using my_type = typename my_type_t<T>::type;

template <typename T>
class myClass
{
public:
    // Many methods...
protected:
private:
    my_type<T> attribute
    // Other attributes.
};
```

Then at least you don't have to duplicate the whole rest of the class again.

But it probably does not make that much sense, as you surely want to use the type somewhere. So you would have to specialize that places further.